# Not all records get indexed in Solr 6.6.0

Tags: indexing, solr

I am using Solr6.6.0. we have 127 000 records in database but out of which only 120 000 records get indexed.

Why 7 000 records are not getting indexed?

Comment: Can you specify more details?

Comment: Usually this is caused by your uniqueKey field (i.e. usually your `id` field or another field that's been defined as unique) having duplicates, in effect overwriting previously indexed documents. The Solr log should show you if there's an issue with any of the documents in a batch if you're sending batches of documents otherwise.

Comment: .. make sure your id field is defined as a string as well, and not a text type.